# Upgrading WP8 to Silverlight WP8.1, assembly issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8, .net-assembly

I have updated my project to Silverlight WP8.1, and updated the different nuget packages. Rebuild, restart, clean and rebuild :)
But I keep getting an error with one assembly for one of my dll's.

> Error 24  Assembly 'MainGame, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=5.1.1.35049, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7570ab207bcb616' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=5.0.2.32240, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7570ab207bcb616' c:\Users\johann\Desktop\StoneGaard\MainGame\Bin\ARM\Debug\MainGame.dll  MVVMTestApp

I have reinstalled and removed and reinstalled the MVVMLight Package. I am sure that the references are new 5.1.1.x when looking in the references overview:
[image: Image of references]

Finally I have tried deleting the Maingame.dll and restarting yet again and rebuilding with the same error.

Can anyone help with solving the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referencing the wrong libraries. (Maybe you pick the WP8.1 **RT** version?) Try using Nuget package installer, so it automatically choose the right ones for your project.

Open `Tools > Nuget package manager > Package manager console` and use this command:

> Install-Package MvvmLight

Nuget lib page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/

Comment: I had allready done this with Update-Package -reinstall, without any success. But Tried your solution and apparently that worked, but got another error in another project, I will ask a new question about that. Thx for your help!

Comment: When troubles like this happen, **never ever** perform reinstall, just uninstall and install again.

Comment: Okay I will remember ! :) But :/ I have tried it now with the new error that I got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090004/upgrading-wp8-to-silverlight-wp8-1-payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-same