# Upgrading WP8 to Silverlight WP8.1, payload contains two or more files with same destination

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone-8, payload

I have updated my project to Silverlight WP8.1, and updated the different nuget packages. Rebuild, restart, clean and rebuild :) But I keep getting an error,

> Error Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Newtonsoft.Json.xml'. Source files: 
>   C:\Users\johann\Desktop\StoneGaard\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.xml
>   C:\Users\johann\Desktop\StoneGaard\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.xml

I found a [solution for a WinRT application](https://cyanbyfuchsia.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path/), but did not work in silverlight 
tried Uninstall the specific versions using `Package Manager Console` and install Newtonsoft.json, but the error keeps appearing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Go to project references and see if Newtonsoft library appears

Comment: @fillobotto It does Version 7.0.0.0, at least thats the info in the properties on that reference

Comment: Remove **every** possible reference linked to that library and then perform a clear install from Nuget console

Comment: @fillobotto I removed them all, but the error persisted. I then uninstalled  all newtonsoft, which meant I also had to remove the mobileservice references. I then reinstalled mobileservice and got the new reference for newtonsoft, and the error persisted :S

Comment: @fillobotto the error disappeared when I right clicked the `Newtonsoft.Json` and set `Copy Local = False`

Comment: That's it's not likely to be the solution. Why don't you try to go to the mentioned path and delete them from yourself?

Comment: @fillobotto I have done this without any success, however removing it removed the error on compileTime, and the no errors so far during runtime

Comment: The only possible explanation I can give is that you aready installed a package that require Newtonsoft. Nuget manager automatically resolve all necessary dependencies and you are trying to reference it twice!

Comment: @fillobotto If you write it as an answer I will accept it, because it was better to have removed then have as `Copy local = False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it using these steps :

- Use "manage nuget for solution" and be sure that all projects are using the same version of NewtonSoft using the "consolidate" tab.
- Clean all projects.
- Rebuild

Regards